Why does workspace keep changing modes?
I have customized workspace that keeps automatically changing from Object Mode to Sculpt Mode whenever I switch to it. I keep changing it back to Object Mode, but when I return to it, it's in Sculpt Mode again. I recall having this problem once before, but I don't recall the fix. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 4.2.0, Windows 11

Thank you very much! :)
